# Why previous customer details are showed in shared preference?

Tags: android

```
 SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                editor.putString("Orderinfo", responseStr);
                Log.i("myprev",responseStr);//storing correct values
                editor.commit();
```

I have used fragments,i stored Orderinfo,its stores the current values but in next fragment page i have to retrive my current customer data,but its shows previously stored customer details...can anyone help me to solve the problem?

```
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
    String emailsts = prefs.getString("Orderinfo", "");
    Log.i("myinfo",emailsts);//this shows prev customer details
```

Comment: U shud share the code.

Comment: only few fields values from edit text,other fields like date,quantity from backend..thats why i stored in shared preference.

Comment: if we see the code we can help u

Answer (score 0):

```
SharedPreferences myPrefs =PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
 myPrefs.edit().putString("Orderinfo", responseStr).apply();
String responseString= myPrefs.getString("Orderinfo", "");
if(!responseString.isEmpty()){
// Do you code
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply sir

Comment: But did it work? It shouldn't take more than two minutes to try this change, see if it's working, and give him an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

String emailsts = prefs.getString("Orderinfo", "");
here "emailsts" is getting null so you will get default value which is blank in above code .which means your value is not Store in SharedPreferences.
And Mau be your "responseStr" is null please put log there and print value.

Log.v(TAG ,"responseStr=="+responseStr);